# Can a class have an object of itself as an attribute?

Tags: java, class, attributes

Can a class have an object of itself as an attribute?

Shouldn't this cause an infinite loop and an explosion?

```
public class MyClass() {
     private MyClass classy;
}
```

Comment: *"Won't this be an infinite loop and cause an explosion?"* ... Only if you *instantiated* it there.

Comment: Why don't you try it? Problem solved.

Comment: yes you can have that

Comment: What do you think a linked list does?

Comment: Wow harsh. Sorry for being a total idiot. Geez it's not a terrible question

Comment: @Imray The question isn't terrible, but it can be checked in 2 lines of code...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I did check it and it worked. I thought it wouldn't. I edited my question to better reflect that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as is

```
public class MyClass() {
      private MyClass classy;
}
```

You can have that!!!

With this though

```
public class MyClass() {
      private MyClass classy = new MyClass();
}
```

you will have problems (`java.lang.StackOverflowError`)

That is because in the first case you have only a local variable **of type** `MyClass`. Now in the second case, when you try to instantiate it, thats where a kind of infinite loop comes and the JVM complains

Comment: So it's legal as long as you don't instantiate it? Then what's the point?

Comment: @Imray - any number of data structures are built around nodes having references to other nodes of the same type; your basic linked-list, for example. You can't instantiate it when *constructing* the object or it infinitely recurses; you're more than capable of passing in a reference or creating one later.